# How do I monitor ColdFusion in Resin?

Tags: coldfusion, resin, caucho

I have ColdFusion 8 installed on resin-3.1.9 (Linux).  On my standalone ColdFusion server, I can use `/opt/coldfusion8/bin/cfstat` to monitor active and queued requests.

On Resin, with ColdFusion 8 installed as a multi-server install, I don't know how to get this information.  Can someone help me?

I have tried server monitor through ColdFusion 8 and it doesn't show me the queued request.  I can't even find that information in FusionReactor.

I tried using `<statistics-enable>true</statistics-enable>` in /opt/resin/conf/resin.conf; however, I don't know where that information is outputted and if it would even help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ColdFusion 8 system requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/systemreqs/), [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/) is not supported.

You may want to use one of the followings to save you some trouble:

- WebLogic 8.1, 9.2, 10
- WebSphere 5.1.1, 6.1, 6.1
- Oracle Application Server 10g R1-R3
- JRun 4 Updater 7
- JBoss 4.0.3, 4.0.5, 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/), it lists Railo Resin support, so it might work for ColdFusion Resin, and you could use the trial to test it, or just ask them.